# GraphQL resolvers vs Mongoose ref relations

Tags: mongoose, graphql, nestjs

I am creating a GraphQL API with NestJS and using Mongoose for data access. I need a general direction for resolving the relational data.

Should I leave all the relations in Mongoose models as ObjectId refs and resolve all of them when needed with GraphQL resolvers with extra queries or should I use Mongoose refs and populate all the related docs manually?

What's the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `populate` mongoose function will do an additional query to find the referenced document. So the two implementations are almost the same thing.

However, in the case of filtering the referenced document, I recommend using mongoose `populate` function because you can use the `match` property and apply the filters directly in the mongo database. It will improve performance because you'll save bandwidth.